# Track changes in configuration tables and create automated scripts to deploy them other envionments

Tags: deployment, configuration, configuration-management, change-management

In the product that I work on, there are many configuration tables. I need to find a way to track configuration changes (hopefully with some kind of version/changeset number), deploy the configuration changes to other environments using the changeset number and if needed rollback particular configuration based on changeset number.
I am wondering how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

One solution that I think could work is to write a script(s) to take all the configurations from all the config tables and create Json file(s). I can then check-in that file(s) to tfs or github to maintain versioning and write another script(s) to load that configuration file(s) in any environment.